# Spring boot. Class run only in src/java/main, in src/java/test it has exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot

1. I have a java/spring-boot class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "ignore")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyApplication {
   @Bean
   YAMLConfig myeadFromYMLFile() {
      return new YAMLConfig();
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
         SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
      YAMLConfig myBean = context.getBean(YAMLConfig.class);
      myBean.doSomething();
      myBean.printApi();
   }
}
```

2. And have config file, what reads data from yml file

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class YAMLConfig {
   @Value("${refresh.rate}")
   private int refreshRate;
   @Value("${datasource.apiUrl}")
   private String apiUrl;
   public void doSomething() {
      System.out.printf("Refresh Rate : %s%n", refreshRate);
   }
   public void printApi() {
      System.out.printf("Refresh Rate : %s%n", apiUrl);
   }
   public String getApiUrl() {
      return apiUrl;
   }
}
```

Question: when I run class MyApplication in src/java/main everything is cool.
BUT: when I run this class in src/java/test it fails

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2018-09-06 17:14:21.389 ERROR 16515 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:19) [test-classes/:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.(ApplicationListeners.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.25.Final.jar:1.4.25.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.ensureNotProgramaticListener(ServletContextImpl.java:875) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.25.Final.jar:1.4.25.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSessionCookieConfig(ServletContextImpl.java:648) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.25.Final.jar:1.4.25.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleDeploymentSessionConfig(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:622) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.25.Final.jar:1.4.25.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:167) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.25.Final.jar:1.4.25.Final]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:284) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:208) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 8 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       ... 17 common frames omitted

P.S.I have spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
With @SpringBootTest I got this:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:19) [test-classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 8 common frames omitted

Comment: can you include your test code too?

Comment: You say you run `MyApplication` class both in `src/java/test` and in `src/java/main`? Is it a typo, or you don't follow the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)?

Comment: It is standart maven project, and this main method is a test. And this method run from main/ but not run from test/, maybe I forgot about some annotation or use  not the right annotation. Or if you know how to do this rightly I will be grateful for your advise.

Comment: I'm not getting why there is a need of having a `main` in your test class. As said by Boris you should not mix two things. For your application, you can have `main`. For test classes `@Runwith` and `@Test` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html
Have all answers on my question.
Thanks guys!